# How to get the w:t content provided a w:p child in xml using xpath

Tags: java, xml, xpath, openxml, domparser

I need to check if a child of w:p have w:t tag in it. w:p can have w:r,w:hyperlink,w:fldSimple,etc as children

```
<w:r>
   <w:t>
   a link 
   <w:t/>
</w:r>
<w:hyperlink r:id="rId4">
   <w:r>
      <w:rPr>
         <w:rStyle w:val="Hyperlink"/>
      </w:rPr>
      <w:t>Google</w:t>
   </w:r>
</w:hyperlink>
```

if child of w:p is w:r then it will have w:t tag immediately in the next level but if child of w:p is w:hyperlink then w:t will not immediate child of w:hyperlink.

The x:path query i have written is

```
Node tNode = (Node) xPath.evaluate("//t", pChildNode, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

where pChildNode can w:r,w:hyperlink or any other valid children of w:p

But this xpath query does not fetch me w:t node from children of w:p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't use any namespaces.

```
Node tNode = (Node) xPath.evaluate("//w:t", pChildNode, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

Before executing this, you have to bind the correct namespace by using a `NamespaceContext`:

```
xpath.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceContext() {
    @Override
    public Iterator getPrefixes(String arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPrefix(String arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getNamespaceURI(String arg0) {
        if("w".equals(arg0)) {
            return "YOUR-NAMESPACE";
        }
        return null;
    }
});
```